# How do you flip/unmirror the video in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: video, microsoft-teams

My team just started using Teams for our meetings, and my video is mirrored. I tried looking for the setting to flip it so that it's not mirrored, but it doesn't appear to exist (unlike in other similar programs, like Slack or Webex).

Can anyone direct me to where the setting to flip the video is hiding (assuming it even exists)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [page](https://techswift.org/2022/03/08/how-to-flip-your-camera-in-microsoft-teams/) shows how to mirror your video. In your case, do the opposite. When you want to join a meeting

> On the Choose your audio and video settings screen, scroll down to Camera in Device settings at the far right and **disable** the Toggle icon next to Mirror my video.

Or if you're already in a meeting:

> 1. Click the 3 dots in the upper right corner of the meeting and select Device settings.
> 2. Scroll down to Camera and **disable** the Toggle icon next to Mirror my video

**Emphasis mine as I have changed the verb click to the verb disable.

Comment: You would think they'd have also put that setting in the device settings that are available in the main window so that you can set it without going into a meeting. (Slack and Webex both have that.)

Answer (score 1):

Open More with the three dots at the top.
Then Device settings.
[image]

Scroll down to Video Settings and toggle "Mirror my video"

[image]